# Invalid syntax python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, if-statement

The else statement keeps flagging as invalid syntax, in the Visual Studio 2019 IDE and when running the .py file outside the IDE. I keep seeing invalid token for else: However looking through the python docs this appears to be correct. I am working on building out a system reboot script to push through a MDM solution. This is just the very basic start of the script.

```
import os
import time
import datetime

WorkStatus = input ("We are going to restart this computer now, did you save your work? Y or N")

if workStatus == n: print ('Save your work now restart will occur in 5 minutes')
    # wait 5 minutes
print ("rebooting in 5 minutes")
time.sleep(300)

else:
    os.system ("Shutdown /r /t 10")
```

Comment: Indentation matters in python

Answer (score 0):

```
import os 
import time 
import datetime 

WorkStatus = input ("We are going to restart this computer now, did you save your work? Y or N") 

if workStatus == n:  
    print ('Save your work now restart will occur in 5 minutes') 
    # wait 5 minutes 
    print ("rebooting in 5 minutes") 
    time.sleep(300) 
else: 
    os.system ("Shutdown /r /t 10")
```